# Get href in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Hey why in the name of god does this return "undefined" on an `<a>` tag with an href?

```
function ajax(){
    $('a').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkhref = $(this).href;
        alert (linkhref);
        }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ajax(); 
})
```

I just don't get it :p. Thanks a lot for your help guys :)

Comment: That function name makes me cringe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var linkhref = e.target.href;
```

Works too.

Comment: thanks. this is the cleanest and works with zepto.js too :). My preference!

Answer (score 4):

$(this) returns an array of dom elements hence href property is not defined. To get href you need to use a jquery attr method:

```
 var link = $(this).attr('href')
```

"this" in this context is the element itself so it has the href property accessible by:

```
var  = this.href;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$()`. It's just `this.href`.

Comment: This is correct. You've combined jQuery and regular javascript. You can either use: `$(this).attr('href');` OR `this.href`